# inner query in laravel 5.3 query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, inner-query

I tried to get data using Laravel inner query like but I face a problem where I pass value variable as value my query is as below.

```
    $seller_name = $request->seller_name;
    $supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
        ->where('company_main_name', function($query)
        {
            $query->select('company_main_name')
                ->where('company_name',$seller_name)
                ->from('supplier_addresses')
                ->get();
        })
        ->get();
```

If I pass static value instead of `$seller_name` then it works perfectly, I checked `$seller_name` is not null, it shows error variable is not defined.

Comment: make sure you are getting `$seller_name` from `$seller_name = $request->seller_name;`

Comment: `$seller_name` has a value.

Comment: @HirenMangukiya Just pass `use($seller_name)` after `function` call!

Comment: @HirenMangukiya got it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to pass your $variable after function with `use` like this

```
$seller_name = $request->seller_name;
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
        ->where('company_main_name', function($query ) use($seller_name)
        {
            $query->select('company_main_name')
                ->where('company_name',$seller_name)
                ->from('supplier_addresses')
                ->get();
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass variable in function **use ($seller_name)**

```
$seller_name = $request->seller_name; 
$supplier_address = 
    DB::table('supplier_addresses')
       ->where('company_main_name', function($query) use ($seller_name) 
       {
              $query->select('company_main_name')
                    ->where('company_name',$seller_name) 
                    ->from('supplier_addresses') ->get(); 
       }) 
    ->get();
```

You can refer doc here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `use` like

```
$seller_name = $request->seller_name;
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
    ->where('company_main_name', function($query) use ($seller_name)
    {
        $query->select('company_main_name')
            ->where('company_name',$seller_name)
            ->from('supplier_addresses')->get();
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass variable to anonymous function with `use ($seller_name)`

```
$seller_name = $request->seller_name;
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
    ->where('company_main_name', function($query) use ($seller_name)
    {
        $query->select('company_main_name')
            ->where('company_name',$seller_name)
            ->from('supplier_addresses')
            ->get();
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$seller_name = $request->seller_name;
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
        ->where('company_main_name', function($query ) use($seller_name)
        {
            $query->select('company_main_name')
                ->where('company_name',$seller_name)
                ->from('supplier_addresses')
                ->get();
        })
        ->get();
```

you forgot to use `use`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$seller_name` to the closure using `use`. Don't use `get()` in the closure query to get your result with a single database query.

```
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
    ->where('company_main_name', function($query) use ($seller_name) {
        $query->select('company_main_name')
            ->where('company_name', $seller_name)
            ->from('supplier_addresses');
    })
    ->get();
```

Also your code does the same as this.

```
$supplier_address = DB::table('supplier_addresses')
    ->where('company_name', $seller_name)
    ->get();
```